# record which contain more than 562mb BLOB is not inserting in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration, database-performance, database-administration

I have table ATTACHMENT contain two columns.
attachment id ---> type INT
attachdata ----> type longblob.

attachdata column value contains 562MB size.

I am migrating data from oracle to MySQL using the ESF data migration tool.
it takes so many hours of time to insert data into MySQL if data is more than 500MB.
I am not getting any error also. I am able to insert the data up to 400MB.
should I change any configuration in my.ini file to insert large-sized data?
how to insert large size data?

Comment: What is `SELECT @@max_allowed_packet;`? *I am not getting any error also.* Have you looked in MySQL's Error Log? third-party tool may hide some errors deciding that it recovers by auto-reconnection...

Comment: @Akina in my.ini file value is max_allowed_packet=800M. after I run above query output is 838860800

Comment: i did not get any error in error log file

Comment: How are you doing the INSERT?  LOAD DATA?  INSERT?  from mysqldump?  from a client?  other?  What is the blob?  an image?  actually text?  other?

Comment: @ricj James I am inserting the data using 3rd party tool called ESF. It retrieve the data from oracle and insert in mysql. This blob is pdf

Answer (score 0):

Set max_allowed_packet to the max:  1073741824

Then hope that ESF is not converting the blob to hex, necessitating 2*562MB.